# Searching a number in a string field with query_string on Elasticsearch

Tags: string, search, elasticsearch, query-string

Among other text fields, I've got this string field in my Elasticsearch index:

```
"user": { "type": "string", "analyzer": "simple", "norms": { "enabled": False } }
```

It gets filled with a typical username, e.g. "simon".

Using query_string I can limit my search results for "other search terms" to this particular user:

```
'query': { 'query_string': { 'query': 'user:simon other search terms' } }
```

Default operator is set to "AND". However, in case a username only consists of a number (saved and indexed as string), Elasticsearch appears to ignore the "user:..." statement. For example:

```
'query': { 'query_string': { 'query': 'user:111 other search terms' } }
```

yields the same results as

```
'query': { 'query_string': { 'query': 'other search terms' } }
```

Any idea what might be the cause or how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the `simple` tokenizer. As the [documentation says](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-simple-analyzer.html#analysis-simple-analyzer):

> An analyzer of type simple that is built using a Lower Case Tokenizer.

And the lower case tokenizer [uses the letter tokenizer and the lower case token filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenizer.html#analysis-lowercase-tokenizer). The problem with your specific test data is that the letter tokenizer divides the text at non-letters. And the digits are non-letters. [This method from Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29) defines what exactly is a letter. In contrast, [this method from Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29) defines what exactly is a digit.

You may want to look at the `standard` tokenizer instead.

Comment: Thanks :-) That was it. Found it out after an hour poking around :-D